# Flume KafkaChannel without KafkaSink?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to write from Flume source to Kafka topic. There is kafka channel in flume and in this [Cloudera post](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_flume.html#concept_rsb_tyb_kv__section_mqc_tyb_kv) author says that kafka channel may be used

> To write to Kafka directly from Flume sources without additional buffering.

But when I'm trying to exclude sink from my configuration flume says

> An error occurred while validating this configuration: Component tier1.sinks: Property value missing.

Do I really need to write to kafka channel and read back to write again to the kafka sink? That seems strange for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to do that, please show me your config file.

A sample in Flume 1.7 goes like this:

```
source config etc...

agent1.channels.channel_sample.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
agent1.channels.channel_sample.kafka.bootstrap.servers = hostnameorip:9092,hostnameorip:9092
agent1.channels.channel_sample.kafka.topic = topic_sample
agent1.channels.channel_sample.kafka.consumer.group.id = consumer_group_sample
```

If you don't need any sink binding to this channel_sample, **kafka.consumer.group.id** is not essential.

See https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#kafka-channel for more

Take care there is a mistake in the document that default value of **kafka.consumer.auto.offset.reset** is earliest not latest

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've solved this problem by using HDFS sink. I really needed it, so it wasn't just a dirty hack :) Anyway it's nice to hear that my understanding of this channel type was correct.